# JPlayer can't get played in IE8

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, jplayer, es5-shim

I have a problem with jPplayer in IE8. I'm working on an application which should support IE8. It works in every other version >8 of IE and plays on chrome and firefox. I googled it with multiple keywords and changed it based on different scenario but I couldn't find any reason why it's not working. Still I can play the demo page in jplayer site with IE8. The other possibility was wrong swfpath which I tested it and change the *"solution"* to just flash and it plays in other version of IE. 
The error that i'm getting is:

```
TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method<div id=player1 class=ng-isolate-scope  data-audio-src="generateLink(answer.literalValue)" im-audio-player>
```

Here is my piece of code related to jplayer.

```
            var idSelector = '#'+scope.id;
             var player = $(idSelector+" .jp-jplayer");
             player.jPlayer({
                    ready: function () {
                      $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                        mp3: "http://jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-07-Bubble.mp3"//scope.audioSrc
                      });
                    },
                    swfPath:"angular/experience-detail/audio-player/jplayer/",
                    supplied: "mp3, ogv",
                    errorAlerts:"true",
                    cssSelectorAncestor: "",
                    solution:"html,flash",
                    duration: true,
                    toggleDuration: true,
                    cssSelector: {
                      title: idSelector+" .title",
                      stop: idSelector +" .stop",
                      mute: idSelector +" .mute",
                      unmute: idSelector +" .unmute",
                      currentTime: idSelector +" .currentTime",
                      duration: idSelector +" .duration"
                    },
                    size: {
                      width: "0px",
                      height: "0px"
                    }
              });
             $(idSelector+" .play").click(function(){
                 if(player.data().jPlayer.status.paused){
                     player.jPlayer("play");
                     $(idSelector+' .active-border').addClass("playing");
                     $(idSelector+" .audio-player-container").css({"border-color":"#c4ebff"});
                 }else{
                     player.jPlayer("pause");
                 }
             });
```

I really appreciate every suggestion.

EDIT:After some digging I figured out that this is not because of jplayer and it's because of angularjs which is not fully compatible with IE8. So I added es5-shim.min.js to my path and it fixed the problem.
Basically I added this peice of code to my program and now everything is working well. for more information you can check out their [github page.](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim)

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="bower_components/html5shiv/dist/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/es5-shim/es5-shim.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging I figured out that this is not because of jplayer and it's because of angularjs which is not fully compatible with IE8. So I added [es5-shim.min.js](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim) to my path and it fixed the problem.